# Minecraft xbox differences with PC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

My wife and I just got the Xbox version of Minecraft and cannot figure out what version it is running compared to the PC. We have been playing the PC for around 2 years now and when we switched, it seemed like we went back in Minecraft time. With limited room to play and a lot less crafting recipes. What version of Minecraft does the Xbox run?